# Bamboo CI Plan Templates?

Tags: templates, continuous-integration, bamboo

Many of my project builds utilize the same stages, jobs and tasks over and over again. Is there any way to define a "template" plan and use it to make other templated plans from? I'm *not* talking about cloning, because with cloning, you are then able to make independent changes to all the clones.

What I want is a way to template, say, 10 different plans, and then if I want to add a new job/task to all of them, I would only need to change the template and that would ripple out into all the plans utilizing the template.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Bamboo specs are the way to go for this: CI/CD as code, either Java or YAML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That isn't currently possible, unfortunately:

A fairly old feature request for [plan templates to reuse across projects (BAM-907)](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-907) has been resolved as *Fixed* due to the [introduction of plan branches](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-907?focusedCommentId=303440&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-303440) in Bamboo 4.0 (see [Using plan branches](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Using+plan+branches) for details):

> Plan Branches are a Bamboo Plan configuration that represent a branch in your version control system. They inherit all of the configuration defined by the parent Plan, except that instead of building against the repository's main line, they build against a specified branch. It is also worth noting that only users with edit access to the Plan can create Plan Branches that inherit from that plan.

While plan branches are a killer simplification for typical Git workflows around feature branches and pull requests indeed and might help accordingly, they neither fully cover the original request nor yours, presumably - that aspect is meanwhile tracked via [Add possibility to create plan templates and choose a template when creating a plan (BAM-11380)](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-11380) and esp. [Build and deployment templates (BAM-13600)](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-13600), with the latter featuring a somewhat [promising comment from January 2014](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-13600?focusedCommentId=557607&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-557607):

> Thank you for reporting this issue. We've been thinking about templates a lot over the last few months. When we've got more news to share on this, we will be sure to update this ticket.

Comment: does bamboo at least expose the specific build jobs to some sort of config artifact that can be kept in source control? I'd even settle for manually doctoring up some scripting technique to flush out a template update solution for all downstream jobs using  some home brewed approach if it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is closed, just wanted to add something I bumped into today:

https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/PLATFORM-48

By the looks of this (issue in review at the time of this comment) we should be able to use templates for Bamboo plans pretty soon.